# torbrowser-install-4.5.1 installation problem on Windows XP

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help, support

I have downloaded torbrowser-install-4.5.1_en-US.exe on my Windows XP based computer and when I double-click on it nothing happens. No error messages, no window, nothing...
I have already installed torbrowser previous releases (I'm currently using v4.0.8) but I have never encoutered such problem.
I have also tried another package (torbrowser-install-4.5.1_fr.exe) but with the same effects.

So if someone could help me, it would be kind.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but Windows XP is no longer supported and shouldn't be used especially when security is important. I don't know if it's so outdated that the Tor Browser won't work on it though.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Tor Browser Bundle.

Right-click the application file.

At the bottom, click "Properties".

You will see a notice that says "This program seems to have come from another computer.." Click the box to enable and then click on apply.

Now, double-click the file, Tor install modal opens on screen.